# How to parameterize an object in integration flow?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I has integration flow for polling data from database. I set up message source which return list of object, this list I want to pass to method `handle` in subFlow.

It's code for this goals, but I get a compilation error: incompatible types Message to List.

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow(
            DataSource dataSource,
            MessageHandler amqpHandler,
            PersonService personService,
            PersonChecker personChecker) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(getMessageSource(personService::getPersons), e -> e.poller(getPollerSpec()))
                .wireTap(subFlow -> subFlow.handle(personChecker::checkPerson))
                .split()
                .publishSubscribeChannel(pubSub -> pubSub
                        .subscribe(flow -> flow.bridge()
                                .transform(Transformers.toJson())
                                .handle(amqpHandler))
                        .subscribe(flow -> flow.bridge()
                                .handle(personService::markAsSent)))
                .get();
    }
```

I know about solution to pass service and name of method `handle(personChecker, checkPerson)`, but it's not suitable for me.

Is exists possibility to pass in `wireTap` subflow in method `handle` list with objects `Person` instead Message message?

Answer (score 0):

```
.handle((p, h) -> personService.checkPerson(p))
```